# Implement Facebook styled sliding menu sliding from right to left

Tags: android, menu, sliding

I tried to implement sliding menu in my application. What i want is that there is a button on the top right corner of the screen. And sliding menu should come up from right to left which is reverse slide of facebook styled sliding. In [Jfeinstein Sliding Menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), Sliding menu come out from left to right. I tried to implement the source to make it happen from right to left. But unfortunately, I still can't get it. Any ideas would be appreciate.

Comment: sliding drawer comes out from left to right try that and customize as  per your needs

Comment: @droidhot yes i already checked it out. The problem is that i can't find the codes which is written for sliding. May be i am too naive to find out. any ideas ?

Comment: you dont need any code to slide a sliding drawer just a handler button by defining it in sliding drawer android:handle="@+id/handle"

Answer (score 1):

There is a [branch](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/slidingright) called "sliding right" in Jfeinstein Sliding Menu on github.

Answer (score 0):

This is a demo project to explore how to implement a sliding menu like Facebook and others use.

[android-sliding-menu-demo](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo)

[android-fb-like-slideout-navigation](https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation)

Answer (score -3):

I made a video (3 parts) on youtube on how to make a sliding menu like the on you are looking for. I show you how to set up the project and get everything linked up.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJJMyzdB9uI

The cool thing about ECSlidingViewController (Its the one I use) is that just about everything you want to configure (how far a view slides, the animations, left or right side) is done with a single line of code. When setting it up, I tell you where you can change it to be left or right side.

Hope this helps.